# How to implement Face masking on live camera?

Tags: android, image-processing, augmented-reality, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm new in this subject but i tried a lots to detect face and draw face points but i'm not able to do face masking in live camera.

I tried [Mood me SDK.](http://www.mood-me.com/).

How can i implement face masking like snapchat and B612 etc.. application in android.

Comment: did you find any library of details about Face Masking on live camera?

Comment: yes @RaviMakvana

Comment: like snap chat and other app

Comment: yes same as snap chat & B612

Comment: can you give me detail which one tools or library are you used for create face masking on live Camera

Comment: Any progress brother? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Please inform if you find anything

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [MirrorReality](http://luxand.com/mirror-reality).

Comment: Not yet but we will use , can you have any other idea about this ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Sorry, I can't. I was looking for libraries for face masking and stumbled upon this one.